# i've deleted a msgstore.db.crypt14 file recently and i need to recover it, i've tried many recover tools but they all failed, is there any method?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, file-system

i tried many recovery software but they only recover some photos and videos or pdf files, is there an powerful recovery software that can recover database files ?, the file is 60MB and i deleted it recently by mistake.

Comment: What Android version is installed on the phone? If it is 11 or higher then it uses File Based Encryption which means recovery of files is next to impossible even if you would have root access.